# Error in `mythfilldatabase' when running MythTv-Setup

Tags: mythtv

I have installed MythTv using

```
apt-get install mythtv
```

and when I run

```
mythtv-setup
```

I get

```
*** Error in `mythfilldatabase': realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fd49cc96840 ***
Aborted
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you: 1/ reboot, 2/ do the exact same thing, 3/ run `sudo grep --ignore-case mythfilldatabase /var/log/syslog`, 4/ [edit] your question and add the output?